# Where can I search for high quality telescope images of Earth's moon?

Tags: astronomy, moon, data

I am developing a sensor calibration capability that compares a telescope lunar observation to  a physics-based radiometric model.  I'd like to find some high quality lunar images  to test our solution against a wide range of data.  To be useful, I need several key pieces of metadata:

- Raw camera data or close to it
- Spectral band
- Exposure time
- Observer location
- Date and time of the collection

My searches of open-source astronomy sites suggest that the focus of most astronomical observatories is deep space.  So the question is, "Where should I look or who should I contact for this sort of data?"

Comment: Would taking your own image with an SLR not be good enough? Also, are you looking for a single exposure to cover the *whole* Moon? It is after all quite large.

Comment: For starters, I'm looking for single exposures that cover the whole moon.  I suspect our tools will be compatible with an image of a small fraction of the moon (I know Hubble has taken some close-ups).  If I had a nice quality SLR with a telescope, that would be a decent solution, but I was really hoping to find some prior work I could re-use.  I'm in discussions with a landscape photographer about using his work.

Answer (score 1):

Nasa [Planetary Data System](http://pds.jpl.nasa.gov/) ESO [data archive](http://archive.eso.org/cms.html) - but as you say, they don't spend a lot of time observing the moon